# kvm+vfio+vga passthrough, got "root.1" not found

Tags: linux, vga, linux-kvm

I have a 64bit windows VM using KVM. I want to try VGA passthrough. I started my VM with:

```
qemu-system-x86_64\
 -monitor stdio\
 -enable-kvm -m 2048 -no-fd-bootchk -localtime -M q35\
 -bios /usr/share/qemu/bios.bin\
 -hda /home/xi/.aqemu/Windows_XP_x64_HDA.img -boot once=c,menu=off -net nic,vlan=0 -net user,vlan=0\
 -name "Windows XP x64"\
 -device vfio-pci,host=01:00.0,bus=root.1,addr=00.0,multifunction=on,x-vga=on\
 -vga none
```

But I got this error immediately:

```
QEMU 2.1.2 monitor - type 'help' for more information
(qemu) qemu-system-x86_64: -device vfio-pci,host=01:00.0,bus=root.1,addr=00.0,multifunction=on,x-vga=on: Bus 'root.1' not found
```

I prepared my system by following [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=162768&p=1) guide.

My hardware (laptop):

- Intel core i5
- Intel IGD and Nvidia m630 (I guess?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't include something like:

```
-device ioh3420,bus=pcie.0,addr=1c.0,multifunction=on,port=1,chassis=1,id=root.1
```

before:

```
-device vfio-pci,host=01:00.0,bus=root.1,addr=00.0,multifunction=on,x-vga=on
```

ioh3420 is PCI-E root port driver emulated by QEMU needed to connect PCI-E devices.

A second problem, that you will probably encounter is, that your graphics card have audio interfaces, which you should add as well.

My working command is:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -M q35 -m 2048 -smp 4,sockets=2,cores=2,threads=1 -cpu kvm64 -device ioh3420,bus=pcie.0,addr=1c.0,multifunction=on,port=1,chassis=1,id=root.1 -device vfio-pci,host=01:00.0,bus=root.1,addr=00.0,multifunction=on,romfile=gpu0.rom,x-vga=on -device vfio-pci,host=01:00.1,bus=root.1,addr=00.1 -drive file=cdrom.iso,id=isocd -device ide-cd,bus=ide.1,drive=isocd -drive file=hdd.img,id=hdd -device ide-hd,bus=ide.0,drive=hdd -rtc base=localtime -boot d -vga none -bios /usr/share/seabios/bios.bin
```

Comment: What is `ioh3420` for? If I need to add it, I need to know where it is on my system. How do I find out its bus address?